# UFuncNoLoopError - Python

Tags: python, error-handling, huggingface-transformers

I am working on replicating a large transformers model. It hangs at Epoch 1 and gives this error:

> numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'greater' did not contain a loop with signature
> matching types (<class 'numpy.dtypes.StrDType'>, <class 'numpy.dtypes.Int64DType'>) -> <class
> 'numpy.dtypes.BoolDType'>

It seems to be pointing to this block of code, last line

```py
inputs_pad = []
    for x in batch:
        seq_len = len(x[0])
        visit_pad = np.zeros((max_seq_len-seq_len, max_visit_len), dtype=np.int64)
        visit_codes = []
        for visit in x[0]:
            visit_len = len(visit)
            code_pad = visit + [0]*(max_visit_len-visit_len)
            visit_codes.append(code_pad)
        seq_pad = np.concatenate([np.stack(visit_codes), visit_pad], axis=0, dtype=float)
        inputs_pad.append(seq_pad)
    inputs = np.stack(inputs_pad)

    code_mask = np.array(inputs > 0, dtype=np.int64)
```

I have tried adding dtype arguments without success.